# What is a simple formula for a non-iterative random number sequence?

Tags: math, random

I would like to have a function f(x) that gives good pseudo-random numbers in uniform distribution according to value x. I am aware of linear congruential generators, however these work in iterations, i.e. I provide the initial seed and then I get a sequence of random values one by one. This is not what I want, because if a want to get let's say 200000th number in the sequence, I have to compute numbers 1 ... 199999. I need a function that is given by one simple formula that uses basic operations such as +, *, mod, etc. I am also aware of hash functions but I didn't find any that suits these needs. I might come up with some function myself, but I'd like to use something that's been tested to give decent pseudo-random values. Is there anything like that being used?

Comment: Exactly what was wrong with hash functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider multiplicative congruential generators.  These are linear congruentials without the additive constant: X<sub>i+1</sub> = aX<sub>i</sub> % c for suitable constants a and c. Expanding this out for a few iterations will convince you that X<sub>k</sub> = a<sup>k</sup>X<sub>0</sub> % c, where X<sub>0</sub> is your seed value. This can be calculated in O(log(k)) time using [fast modular exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation). No need to calculate the first 199,999 to get the 200,000<sup>th</sup> value, you can find it in something proportional to about 18 steps.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for LCG with additive constant it works as well. There is a paper by F. Brown, "Random Number Generation with Arbitrary Stride", Trans. Am. Nucl. Soc. (Nov. 1994). Based on this paper there is reasonable LCG with decent quality and log2(N) skip-ahead feature, used by well-known Monte Carlo package MCNP5. C++ post is here https://github.com/Iwan-Zotow/LCG-PLE63/. Further development if this idea (RNG with logarithmic skip-ahead) is pretty decent family of generators at http://www.pcg-random.org/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple encryption algorithm that can encrypt the numbers 1, 2, 3, ...  Since encryption is reversible, each input number will have a unique output.  The 200000th number in your sequence is `encrypt(key, 200000)`.  Use DES for 64 bit numbers, AES for 128 bit numbers and you can roll your own simple [Feistel cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher) for 32 bit or 16 bit numbers.