# Finding value of a simple Pseudo random number generation funciton

Tags: random

I have an [equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) to generate pseudo-random numbers, example function is well-known called `Linear congruential generator(LCG)`. The function definition is like bellow.

> R1 = (a*R0 + b) mod c

I can easily write a recursive function to generate random number when seed value `(R0)` and `a`,`b` and `c` are given. For example

```
ƒunction random (n,r0,a,b,c)
{
    if(n==0) return r0;

    return (a * random (n-1) + b) % c;
}
```

Here, If I want to generate 20th random number, I can call with `random(20,3,5,17,23)`.

My question is ***how can I calcualte value with pen and pencil for a certain value of n, suppose n = 2019?***.

Comment: Note that by saying "with pen and pencil", this is no longer a programming question.  You should edit out those words.

Comment: Your function's cycle is at most 23 iterations, so you can simply run your function `2019 mod 23` times. That's feasible with a pen & paper, as `2019 % 23 == 18`.

Comment: @goodvibration I got your point, thanks for that but what about `a=1345, c=2595, m=3937 and r0=1`?

Comment: Anyway, same answer as the one that I gave you before. The worst case for any value of `c` is `c` iterations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a simple formula for a non-iterative random number sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30415143/what-is-a-simple-formula-for-a-non-iterative-random-number-sequence)

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to calculate would be
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
.............
[image]
 
[image]
Considering [image] and 
[image] 
And calculate everything modulo C.